# Call member function in derived class from another derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance, member-functions

I have a program which has a base class and several derived classes which contain member functions which override the base class member functions.  There is some duplication of code between the derived classes which I would like to eliminate.  In particular, in one of the derived classes, one member function contains some initial processing and then the same processing as the same named member function in a different derived class.

Here is a simplified example:

```
#include <iostream>

class BASE 
{
public:
  virtual ~BASE() = default;
  virtual void A() { std::cout << "In BASE\n"; }
  virtual void B() { std::cout << "Shared by all instances\n"; }
  virtual void C() { std::cout << "Different in all instances\n"; }
};

class D1: BASE
{
public:
  void A() override { std::cout << "In D1\n"; }
  void C() override { std::cout << "In D1::C()\n"; }
};

class D2: BASE
{
public:
  void A() override
  {
     std::cout << "In D2\n";

     // #1
     // D1::A();        // Error cannot call D1::A() w/o object

     // #2
     // D1 *t = (D1 *) this;    // Creates recursive loop
     // t->A();                 // calling D2:A()

  }
  void C() override { std::cout << "In D2::C()\n"; }
};

int main()
{ 
  D1 d1;
  D2 d2;

  BASE *b = &d1;
  b->A();

  b = &d2;
  b->A();
}
```

In the example, I'd like the call to `D2::A()` to chain to `D1::A()` so I see messages from both member functions.  I've tried two different ways to do this (see #1 and #2) which both get errors.

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? virtual methods are supposed to be called through (unique) pointers (or references) to their baseclass. If you need what you want to do I suspect there is a design problem. 
Side notes : In your derived class method A() should be `void A() override`. And you should not be using `using namespace std;`

Comment: I don't understand why you don't just readjust the type hierarchy so that `D2` and `D1` share a common base, which would contain whatever code you're trying to de-duplicate. Are `D2` and `D1` classes whose hierarchy you're allowed to change here? This needs more details. `D1::A();` obviously can't be called in `D2` because `D2` is not derived from `D1`.

Comment: Create a free function to share code?

Comment: Lot of options depending of restrictions and/or real needs.

Comment: Using inheritance as a way to get code reuse is a bad use of inheritance. Code is best reused through aggregation, free functions and/or mixin classes (investigate the CRTP mixin pattern).

Comment: 1) There is a memory leak in your `main` by reassigning `b` to `new D2;`.  2) The `BASE` class lacks a virtual destructor, so if you were to "fix" the memory leak, calling `delete` would result in undefined behavior.

Comment: As the example code shows, I'm calling the function through a pointer to the base class.

D1 and D2 share a common base class, named BASE.  I can move the duplicated code into the base class, but that code is not applicable to other uses of the base class.

Please do not be picky about trivial unrelated issues in a test case.  Memory leaks and destructors don't matter and these comments are not relevant to my question.

Comment: CRTP or a mixin class looks like overkill.  There is some code duplication between the two derived class members, not additional functionality.

Comment: This cannot be done, as described because C++ does not work this way, on a fundamental level. `D1::A` can be called only if `D1` is included in `D2`'s hierarchy. It is not. The End.

Comment: *"Please do not be picky about trivial unrelated issues"* Simpler to fix them to avoid distractions. (especially as for several questions, there are those "unrelated" errors which are the source of the issue.)

Comment: The `D1` and `D2` classes are unrelated, so casting one to the other doesn't make sense.  Sometimes it helps to replace abstract names like `BASE`, `D1` and `D2` with real-world words to help visualize the absurdity of what you propose.  For example if `BASE` is `Animal` and `D1` is `Dog` and `D2` is `Cat` and `A` is `Speak` (as in "make your animal noise now, please") then by having `D2::A` call `D1::A`,  you are trying to get your Cat to say Woof.

Comment: @MikeEager *"I can move the duplicated code into the base class, but that code is not applicable to other uses of the base class."* -- Sounds like you are arguing for defining a class, `Intermediate1`, that derives from `BASE`, and from which `D1` and `D2` derive. Here's a useful trick: can you describe why `D1` and `D2` share functionality? What's similar about them? Did you just describe a definition for `Intermediate1`?

Comment: Then again, if the member functions do not need to access other class members -- as in your example code -- the free function suggestion is stronger than adding a new class. Sometimes what matters most is a detail you did not even realize could be a factor.

Comment: I'm converting code using a switch statement to using derived classes.  There are multiple cases, each of which becomes a new derived class. There is a test for one case which removes a prefix from some input, then the input is processed identically for both cases.  In the old code, the duplication is avoided by a fall-thru.

Comment: @Wyck If you want "realistic' names, try the base class is AIRCRAFT and the two derived classes are F14A and F14B.  F14B is almost the same as F14A, but it has a bigger engine.  A member function in F14B for "climb" might set thrust to some higher value and then do the same as "climb" for F14A.  Nothing at all absurd about this.

Comment: Then "climb" should be in the base class; OR: base class: AIRCRAFT, Derived class F14, then derived from F14 would be F14A and F14B. Hint: This doesn't scale well. Instead you might have a type that takes a descriptor that provides minimum/maximum values that can be checked against.

Comment: @Casey -- No, putting the duplicated code into the base class would mean it is needed by all instances, which is not the case.

Comment: As a note (18 comments in), the lack of conceptual names in your code made the question much more obscure in terms of finding a potentially better solution. The [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) is a problem of asking about your solution, rather than your problem. I think if you had started the question with this in mind, an answer would be much more easy to find.

Comment: @Rogue -- I'm not asking about my solution; I have no solution.  The suggested solutions are putting the duplicated code into either an otherwise unused function in the base class or an out-of-class function.

Comment: Right, but the question has been over-generalized to the point that from our perspective, those are viable solutions, and there isn't a readily-apparent reason why they wouldn't work (e.g. the missing bit about D1/D2 being independent). Making your question a little more specific / grounded in concrete examples might help make the best answer easier to see.

Comment: @Rogue -- I appreciate that, but the original code is thousands of lines long.  I could cut it down to make it more manageable, but it would have the same issues.  This is a general problem: how to avoid duplicate code in independent derived class members.  The choices (macros, out-of-line functions, functions in the base class which have nothing to do with the base class) all appear less than palatable.  (BTW, I thought that the original example was clear: D1 and D2 are independent, not derivable. If they were, there's no problem.)

Comment: I mean, in the simplest case, you can have a common ancestor for D1/D2 that extends from their common parent, implements said functionality, and then D1/D2 can extend from that.

Comment: All that said, if we go back to your original question, it's a night+day difference between what's being clarified in the comments and what was asked. You're interested in avoiding code re-use, _not_ anything to do with chaining calls between independent child classes. A little more careful crafting of your question might've seen it answered in minutes. Also, actually read that XY problem link: it's a common pitfall even for experts.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255181/discussion-between-mike-eager-and-rogue).

Comment: @MikeEager you should fix your question because `BASE *b = &d1;` doesn't work unless you declare `class D1: public BASE` with `public`.  Even though you've commented out your hypothetical and certainly broken code, the remainder doesn't even compile because of this issue.  Cut and paste the code of your question into godbolt and you'll see.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, you can't do `BASE *b = &d1;` unless you declare `class D1: public BASE`.
**Note** the use of `public`.  Otherwise you get something like *'type cast': conversion from 'D1 *' to 'BASE *' exists, but is inaccessible*. (MSVC)

Furthermore, it sounds like `D2` needs to be derived from `D1` so that `D2::A` can call `D1::A` in its implementation in addition to any extra functionality.  This way you can "chain" as you mentioned by explicitly calling `D1::A()` at the end of the implementation of `D2::A`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class BASE 
{
public:
  virtual ~BASE() = default;
  virtual void A() { std::cout << "In BASE\n"; }
};

class D1: public BASE
{
public:
  void A() override { std::cout << "In D1\n"; }
};

class D2: public D1
{
public:
  void A() override
  {
     std::cout << "In D2\n";

     D1::A(); // Chain to D1::A
  }
};

int main()
{ 
  D1 d1;
  D2 d2;

  BASE *b = &d1;
  b->A();

  b = &d2;
  b->A();
}
```

expected output:

```
In D1
In D2
In D1
```

The first "In D1" will come from calling `b = &d1; b->A();` and the second and third messages "In D2, In D1" will come from calling `b = &d2; b->A();` because `D2::A` explicitly "chains" to `D1::A`.

Comment: D2 is not a proper subset of D1; it just has a member function which has code which is duplicated in both D1 and D2. Other member functions in D1 & D2 can be very different.

Comment: I edited the example to make it clear that D1 and D2 are independent, not derivable from each other.